# How to minimize the file size of a bitmap in flash/actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

How to minimize the file size of a bitmap in flash/actionscript.How many ways of doing this?

Comment: How about ByteArray and vectors, how they can help us in reducing the size of the bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI,

If you are using the Flash IDE (Flash CS5 for e.g.) you can set the image quality through the Library Panel.

To do so right click on the bitmap in the Library and select Properties. Then you can set the compression of the image (0-100) and you can see the updated image with the new quality settings. This way you can decrease the filesize of the bitmap which adds up to the compiled swf file's size.

If you load external images at runtime, you can't change the filesize anyway.

I hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: How about ByteArray and vectore, how they can help us in reducing the size of the bitmaps?